# Haskell: foldl error

Tags: haskell

i'm trying to make a hamming codification in haskell, i have a function "calculateParity" that takes a list of pairs [(Char, Int)] which are the bit (as Char) and the index (Int, starting at 1) in the list of bits, the second parameter is the position of the parity bit i'm going to calculate. The first thing that came to my mind was to use fold left with the accumulator being the actual parity of the data bits related to the parity bit. The code i wrote for this is like:

```
calculateParity :: [(Char, Int)] -> Int -> Char
             calculateParity dataBits pos = intToDigit (foldl (\acc (bit, index) -> if pos .&. index /= 0 then acc xor (digitToInt bit) else acc) 0 dataBits)
```

When i try to compile it, this is the error:

```
 ? Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
              with actual type ‘(a0 -> a0 -> a0) -> Int -> t0’
? Probable cause: ‘foldl’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the first argument of ‘intToDigit’, namely
    ‘(foldl
        (\ acc (bit, index)
           -> if pos .&. index /= 0 then acc xor (digitToInt bit) else acc)
        0
        dataBits)’
```

I think it says the intToDigit isn't recieving an Int, instead it is taking son partial applied function, am i calling the foldl function wrongly?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas lee:
**[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**.